# Store data that persist across page using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am working in SPA where I need to store user inputs in a variable and use the same in other pages . My Views are built in Javascript and controller in C#.

I found out Js-Cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) . I was able to store data and use it across screens . This actually stores data in cookies so if the user diables the cookies in their browser then this does not work .

Is there any other way to store the data . Like in Asp.net application we have sessions . Is there any similar concepts like that ?

Appreciate your help .

Thanks,

Bk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sessionStorage or localStorage

like so

(make data persist across session):
    sessionStorage.setItem('key1', 'val1'); //saves the value 'val1' under 'key1'
    sessionStorage.getItem('key1'); //returns the value related to 'key1', here 'val1'

(makes data persist across multiple sessions)
    localStorage.setItem('key1', 'val1');
    localStorage.getItem('key1');

also try "superCookie" for a more sticky solution
Hope it helps :)

Comment: It is worth remembering that localStorage will fail on iOS safari when a user is in private browsing mode, so a cookie fallback is a good idea.

Comment: I agree, use cookies as fallback for local/ses-storage, & use local/ses-storage as fallback for cookies

Comment: Thanks @mkelle. My users predominantly use IE . So this should work without any issues .